# There are no data returning on the table Vue component

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I am new to Laravel and Vue.js. I need to display the data on a Vue component. The tableData variable in axios.get response is not empty and returning an array. But it is not displaying on the table. Is there something wrong with my code? I am following a tutorial on Medium.

```js
<div class="card-body">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Display Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Description</th>
        <th scope="col">Created At</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="" v-if="tableData.length === 0">
          <td class="lead text-center" :colspan="columns.length + 1">No data found.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr v-for="(data, key1) in tableData" :key="data.id" class="m-datatable__row" v-else>
          <td>{{ serialNumber(key1) }}</td>
          <td v-for="(value, key) in data">{{ value }}</td>
        </tr>  
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    fetchUrl: { type: String, required: true },
    columns: { type: Array, required: true },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      tableData: []
    }
  },
  created() {
    console.log(this.fetchUrl);
    return this.fetchData(this.fetchUrl)
  },
  methods: {
    fetchData(url) {
      axios.get(url)
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response.data.data)
          this.tableData = response.data.data
          console.log(this.tableData)
      })
    },

    /**
    * Get the serial number.
    * @param key
    * */
    serialNumber(key) {
      return key + 1;
    },
  },
  filters: {
    columnHead(value) {
      return value.split('_').join(' ').toUpperCase()
    }
  },
  name: 'Read'
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public function getRoleForDataTable(Request $request)
{
    $roles = Role::all();
    return RoleResource::collection($roles);
}
```

**RoleResource.php**

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'name'       => $this->name,
        'description'      => $this->description,
        'created_at' => Carbon::parse($this->created_at)->toDayDateTimeString(),
    ];
}
```

Comment: what you see in console,for this line `console.log(this.tableData)`

Comment: I believe tableData is an array. You should be doing sth like `this.tableData.push();` and not assigning.

Comment: @Gabrielle-M

(2) [{…}, {…}, __ob__: Observer]
0: {__ob__: Observer}
1: {__ob__: Observer}
length: 2
__ob__: Observer
dep: Dep {id: 10, subs: Array(1)}
value: (2) [{…}, {…}, __ob__: Observer]
vmCount: 0
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Array

Comment: @Abiola I've tried and it displays the same.

Comment: Make sure the url is working

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using? Do not forget to run `npm run dev` after creating a Vue component.

Comment: Use a template tag for v-else instead if placing it in the same tag (tr) as the v-for

Comment: The url is working. My laravel is 5.8

Comment: can I see your controller function

Comment: @kas I added the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Controller

```
public function getRoleForDataTable() { 
     $roles = Role::all(); 
     return response(new RoleResource($roles)); }
```

RoleResource.php

```
public function toArray($request) {
    $itemList = [];

    foreach ($this->collection as $item) {

        array_push($itemList, [
            'id' => $item->id,
            'name' => $item->name,
            'description' => $item->description,
            'created_at'=>Carbon::parse($item->created_at)->toDateTimeString()
        ]);
    }
    return $itemList;
}
```

Vue File

```
<table class="table">
            <thead>
            <tr>

                <th scope="col">Serial</th>
                <th scope="col">Display Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Description</th>
                <th scope="col">Created At</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr class="" v-if="tableData.length === 0">
                <td class="lead text-center" :colspan="columns.length + 1">No data found.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr v-for="(data, key1) in tableData" :key="data.id" class="m-datatable__row" v-else>
                <td>{{ serialNumber(key1) }}</td>
                <td>{{ data.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ data.description }}</td>
                <td>{{ data.created_at }}</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: Can i see your roleResource ?

Comment: The problem is the response of Axios get does not store in "tableData" variable.

Comment: try  this.tableData = response.data

Comment: same. No data found. but it has data in console.log

Comment: Your roleResource ?

Comment: I added the RoleResource.php

Comment: Property [collection] does not exist on this collection instance

Comment: try Extending your RoleResource with ResourceCollection

Comment: it's okay now. But still "No data found"

Comment: (2) [{…}, {…}, __ob__: Observer]
0: {__ob__: Observer}
1: {__ob__: Observer}
length: 2
__ob__: Observer {value: Array(2), dep: Dep, vmCount: 0}
__proto__: Array

Comment: In developer tools > network tab > preview  check data fetching right way